# how to measure distance of location using google maps api at javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I want to get distance of location using google map API.

I have a function named `computeTotalDistance` where I am passing the value of distance and converting it into km.

```
function initMap() {
            let panel = document.getElementById('right-panel')
            panel.innerHTML = ''

            let origin = getValueForm()[0] ? getValueForm()[0] : 'pt isiorder solusi indonesia,surabaya'
            let destination = getValueForm()[1] ? getValueForm()[1] : 'kebun bibit, surabaya'

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 11,
              center: {lat: -24.345, lng: 134.46}  // Australia.
            });

            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
            var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
              draggable: true,
              map: map,
              panel: panel
            });

            directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
              computeTotalDistance(directionsRenderer.getDirections());
            });

            displayRoute(origin, destination, directionsService, directionsRenderer);
          }

          function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
            service.route({
              origin: origin,
              destination: destination,
              // waypoints: [{location: 'Adelaide, SA'}, {location: 'Broken Hill, NSW'}],
              travelMode: 'DRIVING',
              avoidTolls: true,
              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            }, function(response, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                display.setDirections(response);
                console.log(response)
              } else {
                alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
              }
            });
          }

          function computeTotalDistance(result) {
            var total = 0;
            var myroute = result.routes[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
              total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
            }
            total = total / 1000;
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
          }
```

Comment: Better use `computeLenght`method. You'll have to import Geometry library. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how to use this function. I did not find the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this problem resolved, i am change my code becomes

```
directionsRenderer.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
      computeTotalDistance(directionsRenderer.getDirections());
      let loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].bounds.oa.g, directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].bounds.ka.g);
      let loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].bounds.oa.h, directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0].bounds.ka.h);
      calcDistance(loc1, loc2)
    });
```

and

```
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
        total = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('total-point').innerHTML = total + ' km';   
    }
```

thank for your help **LuisTavares**